# column spree_preferences.key does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, spree

When I run

> rake db:migrate

I get the following error message.

> PG::Error: ERROR:  column spree_preferences.key does not exist`

Anyone can please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: From my experience errors in Rails are not single line. Which migration failed, what are it's contents?

Comment: some migrations are running but on this point it is aborting ..
LINE 1: ...ee_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences"  WHERE "spree_pre...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences"  WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/use_s3' LIMIT 1

Comment: Where did the migration come from?  Are you trying to upgrade versions of Spree?  If so, from which version to which version?

Comment: I am trying to upgrade from 1-3 to 2-0-stable

Comment: Do you know which specific migration is failing?  The key column was added to spree in 20120831092320_spree_one_two.rb, so if you're on 1.3 you should have that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick solution you can just remove any references to `spree_preferences` in that specific migration. Be careful though, because that has the potential to break things.